# Issues with routes after putting my Laravel 5 project online

Tags: laravel-5

I have a problem when I put my laravel project online.
I extracted the contents of the public folder to the root and modified the contents of the index.php file accordingly.
but none of my routes are working anymore.
please can anyone help me?
thank you in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't move the public folder of a laravel installation.

Your web server must point to your public folder , usually :

`/var/www/website.com/public`

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how can my web server point to the public folder? Thank you in advance for your answer ...

Comment: It depend on your host, you have to search your with "how to move target www folder" or something similar if you are not using a dedicate server with console access.